# Proper way to represent the relationship between various models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 5.1

rails generate scaffold Attendee screen_name:string tweets:integer

rails generate scaffold Follower followed_id:string attendee_id:string

rails generate scaffold Followed screen_name:string
```

When the application is running, a list is uploaded, with two fields:

```
screen_name
tweets
```

Part of the list upload form, is a field allowing the user to pick a name from the followeds table, causing two tables to be filled:

```
attendees

followers
```

The attendees table, will be filled with screen_name, and tweets, and the generated id, will be saved to the followers table, along with the id that was picked from the followeds table.

This means that each id from the attendees table, can have multiple entries in the followers table, and it could be part of an upload for multiple followeds ids.

My question is about the attendee.rb model:

```
has_many :followers, through: :attendee_id_id
```

I am confused on how to describe the relationship with :followeds (or should I be using Followed?)

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate scaffold Attendee screen_name:string tweets:integer

rails generate scaffold Follower followed_id:string attendee_id:string

rails generate scaffold Followed screen_name:string
```

if the above one is your requirement, then possible association of `attendee` model would be like this

```
class Attendee
    has_many :followers
    has_many :followeds, through: :followers 
end
```